# SaltStack: use pure Python for State Files

Tags: python, salt-stack

Since I love object oriented programming with python, I would prefer classes and inheritance to template languages for state files.

There are three python like interfaces listed:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/#full-list-of-renderers

But they are all domain specific languages: The files should start with "#!py", "#!pydsl" or "#!pyobjects".

I could not find a way to use inheritance for defining my states.

Is there a more object oriented way to define states?

Comment: What do you mean with "domain specific languages"?

Comment: I updated the question: The files should start with "#!py", "#!pydsl" or "#!pyobjects".

Comment: Have you tried to simply use classes and inheritance? It would depend on the DSL how to do this of course, but it's most certainly not a problem in py but the rest should work too. You just need to make sure that you provide the same interface.

Comment: You can just write your own python modules and put them in the PYTHONPATH, and import them into salt.

I don't see a real need for this, because you are defining data structures, not writing a program.

Comment: @gtmanfred yes, you are right. I don't do programming. I am defining structures. But sometimes I am missing the flexibility of inheritance. I think structuring with inheritance could be cool. And maybe somehow autocomplete in pyCharm could work. ... I somehow just don't like yaml. This is just a feeling. I can't find arguments for or against it.

Comment: If the pyobjects settings do not work, we would love another renderer which does what you want.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/contributing.html

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/

Answer (score 0):

Reclass (formerly salt-reclass) aims to offer this.

http://reclass.pantsfullofunix.net/

It has grown out of salt to being crossplatform (ansible, puppet, etc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since we will use one plattform (SaltStack) I guess a crossplatform solution would complicate it. A solution which uses SaltStack classes would be better for my case.